# Git push/ pull error

Tags: git, github, ide

I use intellij terminal to get git repo. But when  I try to pull or push I get this error:

> 1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol
>   version.

How can I fix the problem? Help me please.

Comment: Are you using SSH or basic credentials for your authorization?  If the former, then maybe try switching to basic, at least as a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Update your git binaries and/or IDE. Your tooling is attempting a TLS 1.0 handshake which is no longer supported by GitHub.

https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/

> On February 8, 2018 we’ll start disabling the following:
>
> **TLSv1/TLSv1.1**: This applies to all HTTPS connections, including web, API, and git connections to https://github.com and https://api.github.com.
>
> diffie-hellman-group1-sha1: This applies to all SSH connections to github.com
>
> diffie-hellman-group14-sha1: This applies to all SSH connections to github.com

Comment: I use the latest version of  git  and Ide. what else shall I  update?

Comment: It depends on your system setup. If you read the [link](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/) posted by @evilSnobu, it indicates updates to Windows Credential Manager, Red Hat, or Java if any are applicable to your setup.

Comment: ^ Effectively, the problem could lie outside of Git/IDE and we'd need to know more about your setup to be helpful.

Comment: Right, the IntelliJ terminal may run on JDK <8. I am extremely unfamiliar with IntelliJ, but i know it's written in Java so check your runtime version.